# How do i add a version number to npm pack?

Tags: angular, npm

I am working on a TeamCity deployment that includes NPM pack.  I noticed that its packing everything up a filename-0.0.0.tgz.  So I moved to the command line to get it working before running it through TC.

If I run npm pack and the command line I do see it making 0.0.0.tgz.  I looked at npm pack --help and it does not look like version is an option for npm pack.

Maybe I run two steps?  npm version and then npm pack?

Sorry for the newbie questions

Comment: It should be pulling the version from `package.json` (which could be written either manually or using `npm version`)

Comment: That was perfect.  Thanks.  Now off to figure out to to make it match the build number coming from TC.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that npm can not find a version number (respectively it's '0.0.0') within your `package.json` file. You can run `npm version major` so version number will be changed to '1.0.0' – see [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-version).

Comment: Cheers, that was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

"npm pack" does not change version number, which is defined in  the package.json file of your project, check it first.

You can manually change the version in the file or use "npm version" to increase major / minor / patch before packing or publishing.